# DTE - Reading ProjectItem.FileNames in powershell

Tags: powershell, envdte

I am trying to something pretty simple in powershell, I have instance of ProjectItem and I would like read the value of the FileNames property (documented as a string array). However its proving to be quite difficult

```
ForEach ($item in $scripts.ProjectItems) {
    Write-Host $item.FileNames
    Write-Host $item.FileNames[0]
    Write-Host $item.FileNames(0)
}
```

So my goal here is to move some files around a project. The output of these 3 Write-Host lines is

```
string FileNames (short) {get} 
string FileNames (short) {get} 
string FileNames (short) {get}
```

Is there something special I have to do to read this as an array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you evaluate a .NET method without calling it i.e. providing parens, PowerShell will emit the method's signature(s).  Try:

```
Write-Host $item.get_FileNames(0)
```

**Update:** according to the OP the following does work:

```
Write-Host $item.FileNames(0)
```

Comment: Actually: Write-Host $item.FileNames(0) works. I must have missed it somehow in the debug output. It wont work with a ForEach loop though, but that's ok. I'll marks yours as answer as it does explain the "weird output" (the emitted signature) I get.

Comment: none of the 4 options (OP and answer) appears to be working for me =(
`"The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))"` and `CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], GetValueInvocationException` and also `FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseAdapterParameterizedPropertyGetValueTI` when using ` write-host $item.FileNames(0) "104 pass!"`

Comment: well, the Write-Host `$item.FileNames(0)` is working. The types I was passing to it must have changed I guess.