# Powershell get all filenames associated to a ProjectItem

Tags: powershell, nuget, envdte

I want to get all of the files under a ProjectItem with powershell

[image]

In the above I want the paths for the following files:

- Web.config
- Web.Debug.config
- Web.Release.config

I can get the [ProjectItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.projectitem.aspx) without any problems but I cant work out how to enumerate the FileNames array. All of the elements seem to point to the same thing so I think I must be enumerating the array wrong.

```
$projectItem.FileNames(0) => Path to web.config
$projectItem.FileNames(1) => Path to web.config
```

Any number here seems to return the same file path.

**How do I get all 3 file paths from the ProjectItem in powershell**

To try this out put this in the Package Manager Console of a web project:

```
@(Get-Project).ProjectItems | Where {$_.Name.StartsWith("Web") } | Select { $_.FileNames(0) }
```

Comment: From doc: _The index of file names from 1 to FileCount for the project item_. Silly question, have you tried `FileNames(2)`?

Comment: What about using square brackets? `$projectItem.FileNames[0]`

Comment: According to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14369504/dte-reading-projectitem-filenames-in-powershell) parens should work. I have Visual Studio installed, can you give the steps to have the needed assembly loaded in PS to try and help you? : )

Comment: @sodawillow yeah i have tried a bunch of other numbers (2, -1 1000) they all return the same thing

Comment: @Benh $projectItem.FileNames[0] => the name of the property (`string FileNames (short) {get}`)

Comment: @sodawillow it should already be loaded by nuget, just open the package manager console and enter the command from the question (View -> Other Windows -> Package Manager Console, Make sure a web project is selected from the default project dropdown)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. Basically you have to expand the `ProjectItems` collection of the `ProjectItem` named `Web.config`. There may be a simpler way, though.

```
$webconfig = @(Get-Project).ProjectItems |
    Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "Web.config" }

$webconfig.Properties("LocalPath").Value # path for web.config

$webdebugconfig = $webconfig.ProjectItems |
    Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "Web.Debug.config" }

$webdebugconfig.Properties("LocalPath").Value # path for web.debug.config

$webreleaseconfig = $webconfig.ProjectItems |
    Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "Web.Release.config" }

$webreleaseconfig.Properties("LocalPath").Value # path for web.release.config
```

Comment: Youre totally right, I missunderstood what that filenames property was doing. Thanks